# About algebraic closure

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Let n $\in \mathbb{N}$. Is there a field K such that $\overline{K}$/ K is a extension of degree n?

Here $\overline{K}$ implies algebraic closure.

(Note that for n = 2 we have K = $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/artinschreier.pdf